# How can I combine a FXML file and a group in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

So I made a FXML file for a little game I'm making for school and it has some buttons and labels in it, and it has it's own controller. Now I made a group of rectangles and want to add it to the same scene as the fxml file.

```
button.getParent().getChildren().add(group);
```

The code I wrote here doesn't work. Anybody an idea on how to add the group in the fxml file or just render it on the scene?

Rendering the fxml and the group in 2 diffrent scenes does work, so there are no errors.

EDIT:

Application class:

```
package retris;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Arno Vandersmissen, Casper Vranken, Rani Vanhoudt
 */
public class Retris extends Application {

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        this.stage = stage;

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXMLRetris.fxml")); 
        Parent root = loader.load();

        FXMLRetrisController controller = loader.getController();

        controller.playMusic();

        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            e.consume();
            FXMLConfirmController confirm= new FXMLConfirmController();
            if(confirm.close("Close?")){
                Platform.exit();
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("Retris");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your application class?

Comment: You mean the controller for the view?

Comment: Not the controller, no. Whichever class extends Application

Comment: That would be where you add the fxml document to a scene

Comment: Where did you make the group of rectangles? In a seperate fxml file? I figured it would be in the application class.

Comment: Oh no, I have a closs block (the group of rectangles) with a group of rectangles in it. Now if I press on a button in the fxml file I want the block to appear. So I want to load the group of rectangles whenever I press a button in the FXML file.

Comment: Oh. When you click a button, created with your FXML file, you want to update the GUI with new `Node`s? If so, that is a case for your controller - the `Node`s you want to add need a container, of course. Which will be found somewhere in the hierachy of the FXML file that serves as the parent argument for your stage. This means you can inject that "container" from your fxml file into your controller and simply add the newly created `Node`s from there.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll try to translate that into code :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92578/discussion-between-casper-vranken-and-user2651804).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Scene` can only display ONE `Parent` at a time. Whatever you want to display in your GUI would be contained in that `Parent`. Assuming, as you suggested in the comments, that you want to update that parent at runtime, you need to have a reference to whatever child of the parent that should contain your `group of rectangles`.

let's say the root element of your fxml file is `AnchorPane`, and you also want to add the `group of rectangles` to that root. In your .fxml file you need a fx:id tag `<AnchorPane fx:id="myRoot">` this allows you to inject the element to your controller class by use of the @FXML annotation.

```
public class MyController {
    @FXML private AnchorPane myRoot;

    @FXML private void createAndAddRectangles {
        /**myRoot is already instantiated. you can simply add nodes to it at runtime 
        by using onAction="createAndAddRectangles" tag on a button in your .fxml file.**/
    }
}
```